# JNI scope in Java between classes

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have been working with JNI for a while, however what I am attempting now requires me to initialize some JNI variables from one class and set them from another.

My question is, does JNI work the same for every class(i.e no private address space for every class).
I.e, I allocate memory for one file scope variable in my C library(and set it) from one class(example Class A).
Will this variable still have that memory allocated(and set to some data), for me to work with it from Class B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one mechanism I know giving private space is Thread Local Storage.

static allocation or heap allocation (malloc) are shared by all the pieces of code into an executable.

Windows API offers some variation but we use it explicitly.